# Continue with sudoku - how do I scan for next steps?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

I filled some cells, but am stuck here. I cannot go any further.

[image: Sudoku]

How do I advance? How would I scan the Sudoku to recognize next steps?

I've taken the puzzle from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=easy.sudoku.puzzle.solver.free

Comment: Thank you, I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Why are you stuck?  Keep filling in cells with the numbers that they could possibly be, just like you have been, and once you've done that for all the cells you should start to notice some things.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i will try

Comment: Although using more of the pencil marks will fairly easily lead to a deduction of r8c9=3, further steps after that are rather complicated. There are online suduko solvers that give hints and show deductions, and this sudoku needs some very advanced techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: With no 1, only one 3 and one 7 it is bound to be difficult!